# Adding capture button to bottom centre of the capture window

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the react-webcam npm library and currently, the "capture image" button is located at the bottom of the screen as shown here.
[Capture button default position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dZMt.png)

What I want to do is to get that button to the bottom center of the capture window as I've shown here.
[Area the capture button needs to be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuC35.png)

This is my camera and button

```js
<Webcam
  audio={false}
  ref={webcamRef}
  screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
  style={{ height: 600, width: "100%" }}
/>
<button 
  onClick={capture} 
  style={{marginTop: "-200px"}}
 >
  Capture photo
</button>
```

I've tried giving marginTop and marginBottom but couldn't get it done. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: If the answer is correct, plz check it to help others to know which one they should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a container that can wrap the button to give it a **position absolute**:

//style.css

```
 .video-container {
  position: relative;
 }

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```

//your jsx

```
<div
    className="video-container"
    style={{ height: '600px', width: "100%" }}
  >
    <Webcam
      autoPlay
      style={{ height: '100%', width: "100%" }}
      audio={false}
      ref={webcamRef}
      screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
    />
    <button className="button"   onClick={capture} >Capture photo</button>
  </div>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-ardinghelli-mss9c?file=/src/index.js:0-42